How to map a user attribute to a standard OIDC claim in keycloak
I have a docker container with Keycloak.
I am trying to understand how the authentication works, especially with regards to claims mapping.
I have created a realm and in Realm Settings > User Profile I have created a new custom attribute

With this simple configuration, after login from my AspNet Core Razor application, I am able to receive the claim phone_number in token (access_token, id_token, depending on my configuration). The phoneNumber attribute also appear in registration form as well, which is good.
{
  "exp": 1726218720,
  "iat": 1726218420,
  "auth_time": 1726218420,
  "jti": "86a79a1a-ccd2-478b-9b98-6d67e94207a6",
  "iss": "http://localhost:9001/realms/web-portal",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "d7af94a3-a675-4dd1-b58f-8d2baa29c1f1",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "web-portal-client",
  "sid": "8391d1be-584f-4f3c-91c4-55979a57e635",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "http://localhost:9999"
  ],
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "default-roles-web portal",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid profile offline_access phone email",
  "email_verified": true,
  "name": "Tenant Admin",
  "phone_number": "123456789",
  "preferred_username": "tenantadmin@test.com",
  "given_name": "Tenant",
  "family_name": "Admin",
  "email": "tenantadmin@test.com"
}

However, because my client is requesting the standard phone scope
  builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
        // omitted for brevity
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.Authority = $"{tokenConfiguration.Authority}/realms/{tokenConfiguration.Realm}";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = tokenConfiguration.RequireHttpsMetadata;
        options.ClientId = tokenConfiguration.ClientId;
        options.ClientSecret = tokenConfiguration.ClientSecret;
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        options.UsePkce = true;

        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add("phone");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        options.MapInboundClaims = false;

        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("email_verified", "email_verified");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("phone_verified", "phone_verified");
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            RoleClaimType = "roles"
        };
  });

I expected to automatically receive two standard claims:

phone_number
phone_number_verified

Is this correct? I am new to keycloak and mainly trying to match the knowledge I have with other IdPs. I have also checked this question which is very similar but has no answer.

scope is a different concept with claims.

Could you please elaborate more? My app is a web application not an API.

Maybe I missunderstood, but you could try following steps to get a "phone_number_verified" claim.

Add both phoneNumber and phoneNumberVerified attribute to userprofile.


Go to Client scopes, click "phone" scope, switch to Mappers tab then click phone number verified. Make sure this is set to the phoneNumberVerified attribute.


Add the user with this attribute value to true or false.Then after login. The accessToken will contains this "phone_number_verified" claim.




Thanks a lot. The suggested solution solves the problem. However the question was more to understand why the same suggested configuration does not have to be done for the email scope. In case of email in fact, there is no need to add the custom phoneNumberVerified attribute and still the claim is present in the received token.

@user23137927 I'm not sure. But email should be special. If you check the RealmSettings->Login tab, there are even some built-in Email settings such as enable verify. There must be some built-in database behind. By contrast, you cannot find built-in "phone" settings.
